# How to implement a nested iterator class in Java

Tags: java

I have a class, `Deck`, which holds an `ArrayList` of type `<Card>`. I'm trying to implement a couple of nested Iterator classes inside `Deck` (without the use of `ListIterator` - the first being one that simply traverses through the `ArrayList<Card>` held by `Deck`, in order. However, I'm having trouble getting it to work properly:

```
private static class DeckIterator implements Iterator<Card> {
    private int nextCard;
    private final ArrayList<Card> cards;

    public DeckIterator(ArrayList<Card> cards) {
        this.cards = cards;
        this.nextCard = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        if (nextCard > cards.size() - 1) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Card next() {
        if (hasNext() == true) {
            return cards.get(nextCard + 1);
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my `main`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Deck newDeck = new Deck();
        Iterator<Card> iterator = new DeckIterator();
        while (DeckIterator.hasNext()) {
            Card card = DeckIterator.next();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting `constructor DeckIterator in class DeckIterator cannot be applied to given types; required: ArrayList<Card>, found: no arguments`.

Answer (score 0):

As the error says : in the `DeckIterator` class there is only one constructor, and it requires a `List<Card>` but you try to create a `DeckIterator` without any parameter

```
// REQUIRE
public DeckIterator(ArrayList<Card> cards) {
    this.cards = cards;
    this.nextCard = 0;
}

// YOUR TRY
Iterator<Card> iterator = new DeckIterator();
```

---

The default constructor (no arg) is available by default when there is **no** constructor define, it there is one, you need to explicitly define the default one (or give a `List<Card>` as parameter, because here you can't expect nothin in your loop as you didn't give any card)

```
public DeckIterator() {
    this.cards = new ArrayList<>();
    this.nextCard = 0;
}
```

---

**Error** : You did not use the variable name, it should be

```
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    Card card = iterator .next();
}
```